# Spring Restful Service JSON with POST using Jodatime DATETIME returning http status 415

Tags: json, spring, datetime, jodatime

```
$ curl -i -X POST -H "Content-Type:application/json" -H "Accept:application/json" http://localhost:8080/myapp/login -d '{"username":"someuser","password":"0","deviceId":"5","deviceTime":"2014-12-12 11:55:05.987"}'
```

Returning HttpStatus 415

Server side log showing exception with

TRACE HandlerMethod - Error resolving argument [0] [type=com.npt.ws.model.MobileUserLoginRequest]

org.springframework.web.HttpMediaTypeNotSupportedException: Content type 'application/json' not supported

**dispatcher-servlet.xml containing**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
 xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
 xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
 xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p"
 xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
 xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans 
  http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.1.xsd
  http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.1.xsd
  http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-3.1.xsd
  http://www.springframework.org/schema/oxm http://www.springframework.org/schema/oxm/spring-oxm-3.1.xsd">


   <!-- Activates mapping of @Controller -->
    <context:component-scan base-package="com.npt.ws.web">
        <context:include-filter type="annotation"
            expression="org.springframework.stereotype.Controller"/>
    </context:component-scan>

   <!-- Activates @Autowired for Controllers -->
    <context:annotation-config proxy-target-class="true"/>

   <!--Jackson - objectMapper format date setting -->
    <bean id="objectMapper"
        class="org.springframework.http.converter.json.Jackson2ObjectMapperFactoryBean"
        p:indentOutput="true" p:simpleDateFormat="yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS">
    </bean>

        <!--Jackson - registerModule JodaModule -->
    <bean
        class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.MethodInvokingFactoryBean"
        p:targetObject-ref="objectMapper" p:targetMethod="registerModule">
        <property name="arguments">
            <list>
                <bean class="com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype.joda.JodaModule" />
            </list>
        </property>
    </bean>

    <!-- Spring MVC:  setting objectMapper in converter MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter-->
    <mvc:annotation-driven>
        <mvc:message-converters>
            <bean
                class="org.springframework.http.converter.json.MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter">
                <property name="objectMapper" ref="objectMapper" />
            </bean>
        </mvc:message-converters>
    </mvc:annotation-driven>
</beans>
```

**LoginRequest class**

```
import java.sql.Timestamp;

import org.codehaus.jackson.map.annotate.JsonDeserialize;
import org.codehaus.jackson.map.annotate.JsonSerialize;
import org.joda.time.DateTime;

import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonIgnoreProperties;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonInclude;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonInclude.Include;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonProperty;
import com.npt.ws.utils.CustomDateDeSerializer;
import com.npt.ws.utils.CustomDateSerializer;

public class MobileUserLoginRequest {
    private String username;
    private String password;
    private String deviceId;
    private String deviceName;
    private String devicePhoneNum;
    private String serviceCarrierId;
    private String deviceType;
    private String deviceOS;
    private String browserName;
    private String browserVersion;
    private String deviceModel;
    private String appVersion;
    private DateTime deviceTime;
    private Double lattitude;
    private Double longitude;
    private String devicePowerStatus;
    private Integer deviceBatteryRemaining;
    private Integer appRAMUsed;
    private Integer deviceAvailableRAM;
    private Integer deviceSDAvailableSpace;
    private String ipAddress;
    private String locationAPI;
    private String locationAPIAccuracy;

    public MobileUserLoginRequest() {
        super();
    }


    public MobileUserLoginRequest(String username, String password,
            String deviceId) {
        super();
        this.username = username;
        this.password = password;
        this.deviceId = deviceId;
    }


    public String getUsername() {
        return username;
    }
    public void setUsername(String username) {
        this.username = username;
    }
    public String getPassword() {
        return password;
    }
    public void setPassword(String password) {
        this.password = password;
    }
    public String getDeviceId() {
        return deviceId;
    }
    public void setDeviceId(String deviceId) {
        this.deviceId = deviceId;
    }
    public String getDeviceName() {
        return deviceName;
    }
    public void setDeviceName(String deviceName) {
        this.deviceName = deviceName;
    }
    public String getDevicePhoneNum() {
        return devicePhoneNum;
    }
    public void setDevicePhoneNum(String devicePhoneNum) {
        this.devicePhoneNum = devicePhoneNum;
    }
    public String getServiceCarrierId() {
        return serviceCarrierId;
    }
    public void setServiceCarrierId(String serviceCarrierId) {
        this.serviceCarrierId = serviceCarrierId;
    }
    public String getDeviceType() {
        return deviceType;
    }
    public void setDeviceType(String deviceType) {
        this.deviceType = deviceType;
    }
    public String getDeviceOS() {
        return deviceOS;
    }
    public void setDeviceOS(String deviceOS) {
        this.deviceOS = deviceOS;
    }
    public String getBrowserName() {
        return browserName;
    }
    public void setBrowserName(String browserName) {
        this.browserName = browserName;
    }
    public String getBrowserVersion() {
        return browserVersion;
    }
    public void setBrowserVersion(String browserVersion) {
        this.browserVersion = browserVersion;
    }
    public String getDeviceModel() {
        return deviceModel;
    }
    public void setDeviceModel(String deviceModel) {
        this.deviceModel = deviceModel;
    }
    public String getAppVersion() {
        return appVersion;
    }
    public void setAppVersion(String appVersion) {
        this.appVersion = appVersion;
    }
    //@JsonSerialize(using = CustomDateSerializer.class)
    public DateTime getDeviceTime() {
        return deviceTime;
    }
    //@JsonDeserialize(using = CustomDateDeSerializer.class)
    public void setDeviceTime(DateTime deviceTime) {
        this.deviceTime = deviceTime;
    }
    public void setDeviceTime(Timestamp deviceTime) {
        this.deviceTime = new DateTime(deviceTime.getTime());
    }
    public Double getLattitude() {
        return lattitude;
    }
    public void setLattitude(Double lattitude) {
        this.lattitude = lattitude;
    }
    public Double getLongitude() {
        return longitude;
    }
    public void setLongitude(Double longitude) {
        this.longitude = longitude;
    }
    public String getDevicePowerStatus() {
        return devicePowerStatus;
    }
    public void setDevicePowerStatus(String devicePowerStatus) {
        this.devicePowerStatus = devicePowerStatus;
    }
    public Integer getDeviceBatteryRemaining() {
        return deviceBatteryRemaining;
    }
    public void setDeviceBatteryRemaining(Integer deviceBatteryRemaining) {
        this.deviceBatteryRemaining = deviceBatteryRemaining;
    }
    public Integer getAppRAMUsed() {
        return appRAMUsed;
    }
    public void setAppRAMUsed(Integer appRAMUsed) {
        this.appRAMUsed = appRAMUsed;
    }
    public Integer getDeviceAvailableRAM() {
        return deviceAvailableRAM;
    }
    public void setDeviceAvailableRAM(Integer deviceAvailableRAM) {
        this.deviceAvailableRAM = deviceAvailableRAM;
    }
    public Integer getDeviceSDAvailableSpace() {
        return deviceSDAvailableSpace;
    }
    public void setDeviceSDAvailableSpace(Integer deviceSDAvailableSpace) {
        this.deviceSDAvailableSpace = deviceSDAvailableSpace;
    }

    public String getIpAddress() {
        return ipAddress;
    }
    public void setIpAddress(String ipAddress) {
        this.ipAddress = ipAddress;
    }
    public String getLocationAPI() {
        return locationAPI;
    }
    public void setLocationAPI(String locationAPI) {
        this.locationAPI = locationAPI;
    }
    public String getLocationAPIAccuracy() {
        return locationAPIAccuracy;
    }
    public void setLocationAPIAccuracy(String locationAPIAccuracy) {
        this.locationAPIAccuracy = locationAPIAccuracy;
    }



}
```

**Controller containing**

```
@RequestMapping(value="/login", method=RequestMethod.POST,
            consumes="application/json", produces="application/json"
            )
     public @ResponseBody MobileUserLoginResponse authenticateUser(@RequestBody final MobileUserLoginRequest loginRequest,HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse res, HttpSession session) {
        try {
            MobileUserLoginResponse loginResponse = mobileAppLoginManager.authenticateUser(loginRequest);

            return loginResponse;
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return null;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the enum, MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE when declaring consumes and produces.